# Annual Review been made accessible to whole department

Tags: review

My boss, seemingly negligently, made my annual review accessible for viewing to everybody in the department.

How should I handle this situation?

Comment: Please read https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi and welcome to The Workplace!  Your question as it was worded was likely to be closed, as asking what to do is explicitly off-topic here.  I have reworded it to try to phrase it in such a way to retain your intent.  If I have lost the intent of your question, please let me know :)

Comment: Only you, and no one else?

Answer (score 8):

The first question to ask is, have you spoken to your boss about this?  Did your boss acknowledge that this was an issue or a mistake?

The second question is, when you say "made accessible", do you mean it was put in front of everyone or was it tucked away on a file share somewhere?  Was anyone else's review also made accessible?

The third question is, if having spoken to your boss, have you discussed this with HR?  Can they confirm that there has been a breach of privacy?

Your question indicates that you are (probably rightly) upset at what has happened, but the best way to handle this is professionally.  Speak to your boss first, preferably in an open manner rather than being combative.  This way you are more likely to get an apology and the file removed than if you are accusatory.

If you have no acceptable solution once speaking to your boss, then speak to HR.  Remember as everyone says, HR is not your friend, they are there to look after the interests of the company.  Ask them about their policy around privacy of your annual review, then state simply that your review is currently available on such-and-such file server or so-and-so email.  Do not say that your boss has been negligent, let HR draw their own conclusions from facts, not from accusations.  HR can then address the situation in compliance with local laws and corporate policy.

Comment: Thank for you input and your time.  Let me address the questions you asked. To your second question: it was a draft of the review that my boss added to his/her outlook calendar which is accessible by everyone in the department.  No one else's review was handled in a such way. To your third question: I haven't spoken to anybody in HR.

Comment: There is no simple answer to the first question. let's me give you some details: when I saw the review on the calendar I forwarded to myself to have a record of everything.  That action alerted the director of my boss.  The director called and asked me to delete the review and later my boss called me to confirm that the review was deleted.  That's all.  So, my boss did not discuss the issue with me and nobody acknowledged his or her mistake or wrongdoing. Finally, my boss haven't discussed the content of the review with me but it is matter of time.  How would you handle that discussion?

Answer (score 3):

**How should I handle this situation?**

-> go to talk to your boss, and first clarify the situation "Hey boss, it **seems** my annual review is accessible by anybody but **from my understanding** it should have restricted access, would you mind to check it?".

Maybe it is just a mistake from him ( he didn't pay attention to the reading rights of the file), so talk to him casually, don't be agressive about it.

Answer (score -3):

I think because it's about the workplace and about your career, there should be no complaint as long as this is legal and applies to the code of conduct of the firm. The more important thing should be working hard to keep up with the employer's increasing demands.

Suggestion: From my stand, I will have a conversation with my boss about my performance, request clarification about the purpose of his/her action. In that case, oneself should be optimistic and ready to embrace critics.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Workplace!  Your answer doesn't really address the question, and instead comes across as more opinion than giving the OP suggestions on how to resolve the situation.  Can you please try to reword?